# Where can I trade my altcoins?

Tags: litecoin, namecoin, peercoin, altcoin-trade

I'm looking for an exchange to trade my altcoins against each other to take advantage of the volatility. Any suggestions for altcoin exchanges?

Comment: You mean apart from BTC-e?

Comment: btc-e doesn't offer many combinations of crypto vs crypto. Most of their altcoins are tied to `BTC`. [Crypto Street](http://www.crypto.st) is designed to promote altcoins trading against each other.

Comment: [Vircurex](https://vircurex.com/welcome/index?referral_id=230-652) has a massive number of currency pairs they support.

Comment: https://Cryptsy.com accepts just about every altcoin out there. BitJohn

Answer (score 2):

[Crypto Street](http://www.crypto.st) is a platform launched to do exactly this. We support `BTC`, `LTC` and `FTC` for now. We plan to add additional altcoins as they prove viable or in some way substantial.

(DISCLAIMER: I am one of the owners of the site).

Answer (score 0):

Orbitcoin can be found at https://www.coins-e.com this is a new exchange will a massive range of alt currency.

Answer (score 0):

The most popular and trusted alt coin exchange would be btc-e they accept all the 'major' alt currencies

Answer (score 0):

Here we go, this is the best place atm, if you are interested in a big variety of coins -https://www.cryptsy.com/users/register?refid=9754  click there register and start trading today :)